# List all controllers running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I just installed the controller via Helm, I can list the helm packages via `helm list`, but is it possible to list all the controllers running in the cluster via `kubectl` or `api-query`?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is a way to list controllers in k8s. every resource/object in k8s is controlled by a controller (control loop) with spec fields as values for desired state. if you have deployed a controller outside control plane (built-in controllers) then what i will do to find the controller:

1. find the resource/object by running `kubectl api-resources`
2. verify the list and find the resource name
3. search all pods and grep the resource name `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces |grep <resource-name>`
4. the pod in the above search will be running you controller
5. NOTE: the pod name might not contain the resource name but it will contain some similar name. i just share this info to understand what a controller is and how external controller works other than (build in controllers).

more info - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/

Answer (score 4):

If you mean replication controller then you can list them by `kubectl`:

```
kubectl get replicationcontroller -n my-namespace
```

Or list them all from all the namespaces:

```
kubectl get rc --all-namespaces
```

And you can also use API:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/replicationcontrollers
```

**Update:**
You can list other controller types like `replicaset` (`rs`), `deployment` (`deploy`), `statefulset`, `daemonset` (`ds`) and `job` in the same way.

Comment: actually I was looking if it's possible to list all controller running in my cluster, like `https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller`

Comment: I think you want the absolute 'all' controller in k8s.  Don't think there's a command for that.

Comment: That `alb-ingress-controller` is realized by Deployment so you can list it by `kubectl get deployment - -all-namespaces -l app=alb-ingress-controller`

Comment: @Rico You are mixing up resources and controllers. `kubectl get all` doesn't list controllers. It lists **workload** resources, i.e. resources under the `apps` Api Group.

Comment: Does my answer have `kubectl get all`?   I see `kubectl .... --all-namespaces`

Answer (score 3):

General answer ignoring the specifics of the original question:
You could check the `--controllers` argument set for `kube-controller-manager` daemon. To quote [from the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) (as of v1.26):

> A list of controllers to enable. '*' enables all on-by-default controllers, 'foo' enables the controller named 'foo', '-foo' disables the controller named 'foo'.

You can also check the logs of this process. For example, if you have a setup where kube-controller-manager runs as static pod, you can run `kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-controller-manager` (make sure to get exact namespace and pod name right) and inspect the logs. The logs indicate what controllers are started and skipped.
More specifically you could do `kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-controller-manager | grep Started`. This should reflect all controllers that were successfully started and returns output like this:

```
I0114 11:09:28.124108       1 controllermanager.go:622] Started "pvc-protection"
I0114 11:09:28.126523       1 controllermanager.go:622] Started "root-ca-cert-publisher"
I0114 11:09:28.130637       1 controllermanager.go:622] Started "disruption"
(...)
```